# Add product - price and sku field missing

Tags: commerce

When I want to add a product, the field price and SKU are missing.

Running on Drupal 8.7.1 on MAMP on macOS and PHP 7.1.23

Any idea?

[image: adding product]

Answer (score 0):

A variations tab, which is skus and prices. A product is paired to 1 or more variations.

Answer provided by smccabe from commerce slack.